# Warning: Error in parsing value for 'display'. Declaration dropped. Line: 0

Tags: css

> Warning: Error in parsing value for 'display'.  Declaration dropped. Line: 0

I'm not sure what happens when I leave this warning, because I don't see any strange behaviour in any of my pages.

Still I want to remove it just in case, can anyone help me try to find a solution?
Thnx

EDIT:

I just noticed an error in my php script, which caused my object to have `style=display:;`
Now it's solved, thanks a lot!

Comment: First, try posting the relevant bit of code.

Comment: I had similar one for `display: X-)` - what did you try!?

Comment: Well, thats the thing, my code is kinda huge :P. Don't want to post it here. And i don't know which part of it is the relevant part...

Comment: Good idea, post the relevant code. Hint: it's the `display` property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't have too many hacks and overall write neat CSS, try a [CSS validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator).

Comment: The line number isn't always accurate, in the presence of dynamically loaded items. It would be helpful if the initial content of the parsed value were included in the error message text.