# Adobe Edge Animate Stage not displaying Firefox only

Tags: jquery-animate, adobe, adobe-edge

I have a project I started in Adobe Edge Animate, though I have edited the js dom by hand may times over since then. It is heavy on CSS3 animations and javascript. The code currently lives in a codeanywhere devbox, and all systems are go, working perfectly in Chrome, Safari, and even IE10+, however, Firefox will NOT display the stage at all.

**UPDATED DEV URL:**

You can view the new development environment [here](http://preview.zxwzptmjrekoi529ajrx8c4alcdf5hfr55vgw74tjegsyvi.box.codeanywhere.com/damballa-stage.php).

I have Firefox 39.0 installed for MacOS 10.10.3

When viewing my console log in Firefox, I saw lots of css parsing value errors, which lead me here: [Warning: Error in parsing value for 'display'. Declaration dropped. Line: 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3933465/warning-error-in-parsing-value-for-display-declaration-dropped-line-0)

I have resolved all my CSS errors using the W3C CSS validation tool linked in that SO post (except those which target older versions of Firefox), yet I am still seeing parsing errors from other files in my Firefox console log:

```
The character encoding of a framed document was not declared. The document may appear different if viewed without the document framing it.
Error in parsing value for 'left'.  Declaration dropped.
Error in parsing value for 'top'.  Declaration dropped.
```

The framed document encoding error is referring to the two .js files created by Adobe Edge for all of its projects, which end in _edge.js and _edgeActions.js, and those are included as part of the following script:

```
    <script>
   AdobeEdge.loadComposition('dambala-stage', 'EDGE-1396008327', {
    scaleToFit: "none",
    centerStage: "horizontal",
    minW: "0px",
    maxW: "undefined",
    width: "1280px",
    height: "500px"
}, {dom: [ ]}, {dom: [ ]});
</script>
```

And the function "loadComposition" from the above script is defined in the included js file which is called to, with encoding defined, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="edge_includes/edge.6.0.0.min.js"></script>
```

This is also standard for all Adobe Edge Animate projects, so I have no idea how to specify the encoding for those other two js files, or if that might even be the issue at all anyway?

As for the last two remaining parsing errors, 'top' and 'left', those are referring to my main, dambala-stage.php file, though line numbers are not given in the console log so I have no idea what (or where) that is referring to.

Has anyone else ever run into this issue, because I know I certainly haven't ever had a project work in all browsers, INCLUDING IE, but NOT Firefox?

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you are not getting the `This site makes use of a SHA-1 Certificate; it's recommended you use certificates with signature algorithms that use hash functions stronger than SHA-1` error first before all your other errors? enable the `Security` tab in your console to see if you get this error because this is what I get on my end.

Comment: Hey Tahir, thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, I am not able to trigger the error you are seeing on my end. I have tried again this morning from a different computer, this one a Windows 7 machine running a fresh install of Firefox. I do not see any security errors on either machine. Just the aforementioned CSS errors.

I'm going to try moving this code to a real development server and see if this by any chance, has anything to do with the codeanywhere DevBox environment.

I will update the above with the new dev link if that does not resolve the issue.

Comment: Hey Troy, I have a very strong feeling that this is very much due to the security errors I mentioned above. When I looked up the trail, the only reason you are not able to view anything is because you have a **`display: none;`** set on your main **`#stage-content`** element and this *stage* basically gets fades into view thanks to jQuery. And if jQuery gets blocked for whatever reasons, then of course you won't see anything.

Comment: Hello again Tahir, I have moved everything to a live server, away from the Codeanywhere devbox, and, in researching your error message, I found that it can sometimes be thrown when using google api hosted jquery. So on the new dev server I have hosted everything locally, which definitely speeds up the animation effects, but still doesn't display the entire stage in Firefox. Since I am unable to recreate the error message you are seeing on my end, I don't know what else to do to troubleshoot this. Could you please give me some suggestions or point me in the right direction?

Comment: The suggestion that I had in my mind involved hosting most / all libraries on your server. Which you seem to have done it already. I was expecting that this would resolve the issue. Now, is it possible for you to share your live server URL with me now to see if anything has improved on my end?

Comment: Hey Tahir, sorry, yes, I included the link to the new dev server in my updated, original post above. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Did you ever find the issue? I am able to see your url fine in Firefox but I am having the same issue in Firefox with my much smaller Edge Animation file.

Comment: Hey KevinOrin - Unfortunately, I never found the issue with jQuery causing the stage not to render at all in Firefox, but you are seeing it display now because I replaced all applicable jQuery animations and transitions with their css equivalents. This helped boost performance anyway since jQuery animations are a load on the GPU. Luckily, when only animations that could not be replaced by css remained in jQuery, everything worked fine. If you want to reference any of my code for the css animations, the final version of this stage can be found on the live site here: https://www.damballa.com/